# The exact procedure of calculating $\max_{x} f(x,y)$?

Tags: maxima-minima

What is the exact procedure to calculate $\max_{x} f(x,y)$?

This is my opinion:

1. Choose one certain $y = y_0$, and then scan all $x$,find the max value of $f(x, y_0)$ named $f_0$;
2. Choose another certain $y = y_1$, and do the same thing, I can get $f_1$;
3. Repeat 1 and 2, I can get a function named $g(y)$, and $g(y) = \max_{x} f(x,y)$

Is that right?

Similar question: [How to interpret max(min(expression))??](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157962/how-to-interpret-maxminexpression)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that $\max_x f(x,y)$ is a *function of $y$*, so for every $y$, there is some specific value that equals $\max_x f(x,y)$.

**Example**:

For example, taking $f(x,y)=\sin x \sin y$

will mean that $\max_x f(x,y)= \sin y$.